# Strange OpenSSL version

Tags: openssl, version

I've removed OpenSSL in my Ubuntu 14.04 and cloned [Github branch OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable).
I've compiled OpenSSL:

```
./config -shared
make install
```

When I try to run `openssl version` I see the following:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1r-dev xx XXX xxxx
```

How to fix it? Why the command doesn't output something like that:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1 Jan 2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the readme file. It clearly states `OpenSSL 1.0.1r-dev`. The `dev` ending is there because you've cloned the development branch.

I'm not sure why would you want to use some older version without fixes (`1.0.1r` is better than `1.0.1`) but if you want, you can get these from ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/ (`/old/1.0.1/`)

In any case, remember that support for `1.0.1` series ends this year.

> Support for the 1.0.1 series will be provided until 31st December 2016
>   (with security bug fixes only for the final year)

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't notice this line in ReadMe